# After Reseting Password website is not asking for new password

Tags: support, login

I have modified the password of my Stack Overflow account. I am able to login without entering new password on the computer where old password is saved.

How I can force to enter new password to connect to website ?

Comment: This looks more like a browser help request with saved passwords than an SO issue. Could you please clarify? I'm not quite able to get you...

Comment: Have you tried logging out?

Comment: What type of account is it? Truly a Stack Exchange account (email address, password)? Or some other OpenID provider?

Comment: @Arjan, Truly Stack Exchange Account. Not using facebook or  other account.

Comment: Thanks everyone for keeping my account secure on other machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you log out it will log you out everywhere

1. Mouse over your display name at the top, and choose "log out"

   http://so.mrozekma.com/logout.png
2. Click the "log out" button, which will:

   > clear all local credentials in your browser, and log you out on all devices.

Comment: For some reason, I've never used the button yet (close browser=log out, or I'm always logged in)

Comment: If I logout from my machine and log-in again with new password. What will be the effect on other machines where I am already login and logout is not done.

Comment: @Romil: You'll have to do the same. This is usually the case when you stay logged in.

Answer (score 1):

**Clear the browser cache**, That will remove all exisiting cookies and session.

Even if you don't logout, it'll ask you to login. Then you can login with new password. :)

Comment: Removing all cookies is bad idea.